# RevTex-4 footnote and updownarrow don't work together

Tags: math-mode, footnotes, revtex

I am working with the footnote command in RevTex-4, and LaTeC throws errors when I use this with the `\updownarrow` command. The following code has issues:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
    \footnote{$\updownarrow$}
\end{document}
```

However, similar commands do end up working, such as `\leftarrow` and `\nearrow`. The errors that are thrown don't make sense to me; they are errors in the `output.bbl` file, and say things like "missing number treated as zero". Does anybody have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

revtex moves footnotes around. This means that you must protect fragile commands:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}
    \footnote{$\protect\updownarrow$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why \updownarrow is fragile, whereas the other ones are not?

Comment: While `\footnote` has a moving argument in `revtex4-1`, `\updownarrow` is not generally a fragile command. That it becomes so in `revtex4-1` is a by-product of a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in `revtex4-1`, which writes out a `.bib` file using `"` as field delimiter; if, for instance, `babel` for German is used, double quotes used as shorthand would confuse BibTeX when preparing the `.bbl` file and chaos ensues.

This is also the case for some macros defined as delimiters, such as `\updownarrow`: the LaTeX definition is

```
\delimiter "326C33F
```

and indeed you will find, in `aaronNotes.bib` (I named `aaron.tex` your test file)

```
@FOOTNOTE{Note1,key="Note1",note="$\delimiter "326C33F$"}
```

You clearly see what goes wrong: the `"` after `\delimiter` is mistaken by BibTeX as the field delimiter.

Solution: fix `revtex4-1` to use braces for delimiting BibTeX fields.

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

% fix \@endnotetext
\makeatletter
\long\def\@endnotetext#1{%
  \begingroup
    \endnote@relax
    \immediate\write\@bibdataout{%
     @FOOTNOTE{%
      \@endnotelabel,%
      key={\@endnotelabel},% not "\@endnotelabel"
      note={\unexpanded{#1}}% not "#1"
     }%
    }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\footnote{$\updownarrow$}

\end{document}
```

Also `@CONTROL` entries are written with double quotes, but this doesn't seem likely to create similar problems.

**NOTES**

- I added `\unexpanded` for better safety.
- As Ulrike Fischer comments, unmatched `\{` braces in the argument of `\footnote` will break anyhow; in this case, `\lbrace` should be used.

Comment: This solves the " problem, but now it will break if there is a lonely `\{`  in the footnote (less probable, so probably the better solution, but should be noted).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think it's a general BibTeX problem, because it's not able to do the correct matching due to `\{`.

Comment: Yes but in the end it means that either revtex would have to sanitize the complete footnote to get a bibtex compatible entry (imho difficult or impossible) or the user has to be careful and avoid or protect problematic content (regardless if revtex uses quotes or braces for the bib entry).